# Why we can identify $(L^p)'$ to $L^{p'}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $p\in (1,\infty )$ and $(L^p)'$ the dual topological of $L^p$. Let $p'$ such that $$\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p'}=1.$$
Then Riesz representation give us an isomorphism $$\Phi:L^{p'}\to (L^p)', u\longmapsto \Phi(u)$$

given by $$\Phi(u)(f)=\int uf.$$
we also have $\|u\|_{L^{p'}}=\|\Phi(u)\|_{(L^p)'}$

Indeed $\Phi$ is an isomorphism (it's also an isometry), but in what that allow us to identify $(L^p)'$ and $L^{p'}$ ? I don't really understand why we can do that. And we identify them in which sense ? They are the same in which way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If two normed linear spaces are isometrically isomorphic they have identical properties as normed linear spaces. Any theorem proved for one automatically gives validity of the same for the second space. This is the basic idea of various types of isomorphisms/homeomorphisms/iosmetric isomorphisms etc  in Mathematics. Surely, the spaces are not equal as sets but they have identical properties.

Comment: So if $\Phi$ weren't an isometry, the identification wouldn't work ?

Comment: If it just an isomorphism and not an isometry, certain properties still carry over. For example, topological properties not involving the norm still carry over from one space to the other.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your answer doesn't really help me for the moment. It's not really clear... In what having a bijective isometry is the best ? If we would have an homeomorphism would it be enough ? In what the isometry really give the same set ?

Comment: It takes some experience with normed linear spaces to understand what I am saying, but let me try to given an example. Some spaces have the property that $\|x+y\|=\|x\|+\|y\|$ implies $x$ and $y$ are linearly dependent. [ Hilbert spaces have this property]. If two spaces are just isomorhic and one of them has this property you cannot conclude that the other one has. If, instead, you have an isometric isomorphism you can conclude that the other space also has this property. On the other hand, for a property like separability isomorphism is good enough.

Comment: Just a question, if $\|\Phi(u)\|=2\|u\|$ such identification would be also possible, no ? (since distance are the same up to a factor 2). What do you think ? Thank you.

Comment: To be more clear, if $\Phi :(L^p)'\to L^{p'}$ would have be an homeomorphism s.t. $$\|\Phi(u)\|_{(L^{p})'}=2\|u\|_{L^{p'}} \quad (\text{or only } C\|u\|_{L^{p'}}\leq \|Tu\|_{(L^p)'}\leq D\|u\|_{L^{p'}})$$ (but not an isometry) could we have also said that $L^{p'}$ and $(L^p)'$ are the same or we really need an isometry ? Because for me if two topological spaces are homeomorphic then they are  "topologically" the same... but may be in normed space (i.e. topological space with more structure), we need an isometry instead of a homeomorphism. Could you please tell me a little bit more ? Many thank

Comment: The question is whether an isometric isomorphism exists, not whether a  particular map is an isometric isomorphism . If $\|\Phi(u)\|=2||u\|$ then $\frac {\Phi} 2$ is an isometric isomorphism so we can idenitify the two spaces.

Comment: And if we only have an homeomorphism, it's not enough ? Because my teacher said that two homeomorphic spaces can always be identify in the sense that they are the same.

Comment: Two topological spaces can be considered the same if there is a homeomorphism between them. Two normed linear spaces can be considered the same if there is an isometric isomorphism  between them.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't really understand why having a linear homeomorphism is not enough. Could you give me an example of normed space $A$ and $B$ that are linearly homeomorphic (but not isometric) s.t. a property hold in a space but not in an other one ? But if there where isometric, such a property hold in both.